# How can i generate number for same piece of text using VS Code

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, numbers

i have many pieces of code same for example like this

```
alt="Greece"
alt="Greece"
alt="Greece"
alt="Greece"
```

Can i somehow modify it to this? Is there any kind of function like in Excel or something like that please? Imagination write it manualy each is horrible

```
alt="Greece 1"
alt="Greece 2"
alt="Greece 3"
...
alt="Greece 200"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- select the word `Greece`
- select all cases you want with

  - `Ctrl+D` multiple times
  - `Ctrl+Shift+L` to select all
  - use `Shift+Alt+Click` to create multiple cursors
- if needed `RightArrow` to get all cursors after the word `Greece`
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**
- As `Original Text Regex` use: `.*`
- As `Generator Regex` use:  `{{=i+1}}` (watch the space as first char)
- Look at the preview, use `Esc` to cancel and `Enter` to accept

You can use any calculation based on `i` you want and you can also match number in the selected text and use that in the calculation `N[...]`.

You can also add the word Greece by using `Greece {{=i+1}}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.  First, using the extension, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) (disclaimer, I wrote that extension, this is very easy.   Make this keybinding in your `keybindings.json` (after installing the extension):

```
{
  "key": "alt+n",          // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(alt=\"Greece\")",
    "replace": "$1 ${matchNumber}",
    "isRegex": true
  }
},
```

Actually you can make it even easier if you first select what you want to modify (see the demo below).  Then  use this simple keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+n",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "replace": "$1 ${matchNumber}",  // what you select will be put into $1
    "isRegex": true
  }
},
```

[image: add a matchIndex to a line]

---

Another option - not quite as easy

Snippets have a variable `$CURSOR_NUMBER` which is useful here.

Make this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+n",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "$TM_SELECTED $CURSOR_NUMBER"
  },
  "when": "editorHasSelection"
},
```

1. Do a find on your desired text match: `alt="Greece"`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all occurrences of the find match.
3. Trigger the snippet via its keybinding.

Demo of this method:

[image: demo of using snippet with $CUROSR_NUMBER]

So this second method is more steps but doesn't require an extension.